# Confidence Bands vs. Simultaneous Confidence Intervals

Tags: regression, confidence-interval, type-i-and-ii-errors

This may be a dumb question, but when talking about multiple regression analyses are "simultaneous" confidence intervals and confidence "bands" the same thing?

I'm still having trouble figuring this out and how to compute the two things, if in fact they are different.  From what I can tell simultaneous confidence intervals usually refer to confidence intervals that are set such that when used in testing of a discrete number of tests, the type I error rate is controlled by the number of comparisons being made.

It seems to me that a confidence band is essentially the same thing, but that there are an infinite number of comparisons that can be made along the entire regression curve, since any number along the $x$ matrix can be used to make comparison with any other number along $x$.

Is my understanding of this correct?  Are there differences in the calculations of confidence bands vs. simultaneous confidence intervals?

**UPDATE**

I'm still struggling to find an answer to this seemingly basic question, but no one has bit yet.  I'd be grateful for any comments.

Comment: There are two main kinds of confidence bands -- simultaneous and pointwise. If it has no adjective ... just "confidence band" then it's ambiguous as to which one might be intended.